# Can't log in to my android application, facebook sdk 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to implement facebook log in for few days. I want to implement Single-sign on(SSO), but when i am logged to native Facebook app i got this message:

```
"The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. it may be temporarily unavailable, 
the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you  may not have perrmission to view 
this page".
```

I followed official facebook guide for log in.

```
LoginButton connectToFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.lbConnectToFacebook);
connectToFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_relationships"));
UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(MainActivity.this, callback);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Also i implemented:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception   exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i("FACE", "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i("FACE", "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
```

And override onActivityResult method, but this only works if i logged out from native fb app, and as i said i don't won't to use:

```
connectToFacebook.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

i want single sign on.

Comment: have you overcome from this problem? I also have the same issue please help

Comment: No, didn't find solution for this, if you find something write the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

### MainActivity.java

```
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnLogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(session.isOpened())
                        {
                            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome", 1000).show();
                                                                        }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp"
        android:text="@string/login" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.addnewlist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.addnewlist.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" >
        </activity>
          </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Still getting this message: "The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. it may be temporarily unavailable, 
the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you  may not have perrmission to view this page".

Comment: Have you registerd this app on facebook developers site?

Comment: Yes, as i said i followed official tutorial, when i log out from native fb app then i can log in from my app, but my intention was to use SSO so user haven't to insert mail/password every time he want to log to my app by fb.